# Disable ligature for fonts NOT through attributed string

Tags: swift, ligature

My app is in the process of updating fonts to custom one. And with that came ligature issue of symbols kinda merging together. It is very noticeable in an app. Web version of an app dealt with that quickly it seems through some configs, but ios is getting a big issue.

From what I managed to find you can disable ligature of fonts only through attribtued string. But that means that I need to make all of my text in the app go through attributed text... kinda feels a bit counter productive. Does anyone know a way to disable ligature of fonts without going into attributed strings?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SwiftUI, you can try [`.tracking(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/tracking(_:)), e.g. `.tracking(0.1)`.